# How to fetch data from a JSON file using react router loader function or hook?

Tags: javascript, json, react-router, loader

I can fetch data from a given external API using react router loader but I can't fetch from a json file directly using react router loader. I tried multiple times but failed. Pleas help me.

I first imported the json file as blogData.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5SPV.png)

then I tried to use it into the loader function but It's not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4V41.png)

I got this output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwOrm.png)

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include actual code snippets in the form of a [mcve] instead of images of code? Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable with regards to reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON file is bundled with the code, and is imported, then just simply return `blogData` from the loader function.

```js
import Blog from './components/Blog/Blog';
import blogData from './blogData.json';

...

{
  path: "/blogs",
  loader: () => blogData,
  element: <Blog />,
},
```

[image: Edit how-to-fetch-data-from-a-json-file-using-react-router-loader-function-or-hook]

Better yet, since you don't need to really load anything either, the routed component should/could just import `blogData` directly.

```js
...
import blogData from '../blogData.json';

const Blog = () => {
  ...

  // use blogData

  ...
};
```

```js
import Blog from './components/Blog/Blog';

...

{
  path: "/blogs",
  element: <Blog />,
},
```